# LWJGL 2d Lighting (Java)

Tags: java, lwjgl, lighting, light

Me and my crew just ported our game from java2d to LWJGL and want to add lighting now.
What we exactly want to add:

- items/entities that emit light and are moveable.
- Static lighting

We've googled for quite some time now but are kind of lost because we have no idea where to start.
We've seen the alpha mapping method but couldn't really get it to work.

I would be glad if someone could give me an answer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating lights is probably easier than one would think! The following code will create a light and enable lighting, though different parameters can be used also you can change and use things like `GL_SPECULAR`, etc.

```
FloatBuffer ambient = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(4);
ambient.put(new float[] { 0.05f, 0.05f, 0.05f, 1f, });
ambient.flip();    

FloatBuffer position = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(4);
position.put(new float[] { 0f, 0f, 0f, 1f, });
position.flip();    

glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
glLightModel(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_AMBIENT, ambient);
glLight(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, position);
```

Remember that you need to use and calculate normals, because light gets calculated using them.

If you don't use textures and want light to be applied to simple colors, then you can add the following where you initialize your OpenGL states.

```
glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
```

Also if there are some part you don't want to be affected by lighting like UI, then before rendering the UI you call `glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);` and then you call `glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);` again after then UI if you want lighting to be enabled afterwards.

#### Remember

If you don't statically import classes, then just to notify you that `glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);` would be `GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_LIGHTING);` like everything else I just showed you.

Also take in mind that OpenGL only contains 0 lights from `GL_LIGHT0` to `GL_LIGHT7`, though more lights can easily be created within different ways.

**Important** if you think using OpenGL lights will generate shadows, then this code will disappoint you, creating shadows is a combination of OpenGL lights and some advanced FBO work, if I remember correctly.

#### Extra

If you want movable lighting the you just need to update the `glLight(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, position);` each time you move the light.

Here is a little Lighting Types tutorial, I found just by searching "opengl lighting", the tutorial though is written in C++, but OpenGL functions are almost the same no matter which language you're using, only some tiny changes which is easy to spot and change. http://www.swiftless.com/tutorials/opengl/lighting_types.html

Comment: First of all, thanks for the awesome and detailed answer but i think i did something wrong when trying to apply your help. 
cause im getting the following error :

Exception in thread "main" java.nio.BufferOverflowException
 at java.nio.DirectFloatBufferU.put(Unknown Source)
 at java.nio.FloatBuffer.put(Unknown Source)
 at game.Game.initGL(Game.java:152)
 at game.Game.mainLoop(Game.java:117)
 at Start.main(Start.java:19)

Comment: As I can see from that error, you are using a smaller size, than what you are trying to put into the Buffer. What I mean is, if you have a FloatBuffer with the size of 4 you can only add 4 Float maximum. So if you try to add a fifth one, then that error will be casted. So I think your size is smaller than the amount you try to put.

Comment: Well for some reason its not working...
Could you look at this screenshot maybe ? http://puu.sh/3WMWL.png

Comment: Ohh, well take a look at your code, the first one you say ambient.put, and at the next one you say ambient.put as well, the second one need to be position.put, also if that is you rendering loop, then you don't need to place the light in there (you can) but it would be better to place it where you init OpenGL and the starting states.

Comment: Well that kinda fixed it but generated another error:
http://puu.sh/3WNtY.png

Sorry if im a bit hard to teach but we've been coding 4-5 days straight ported our game to lwjgl just ~ 5 hours ago...

Comment: Ohh my bad, I made this post out of my head, so I forgot something, look at the edited code! Sorry.

Comment: @Vallentin Hello. I didn't want to ask a seperate question so I guess it would be OK to ask this here. What I do is I create the light just like you did, then draw a red rectangle which fills the entire display. 

The output is this:
http://postimg.org/image/s8h5iy6pz/

Why is the light black?